# Single page polymer app tries to register elements multiple times when deployed to Firebase

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-hosting

I am using the Polymer starter kit as a reference for routing in a single page app. If I run the app on Cloud9 (the dev environment I am using) everything works as expected.

I run `polymer build` using the polymer-cli and then `firebase deploy`. The same app that runs with no issues on the Cloud9 instance produces multiple errors on Firebase Hosting.

```
Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'my-view1'. A type with that name is already registered.
```

The links are navigating as expected, but the console ends up loaded with errors like the one above. I'm guessing it has to do with the redirect to index.html in firebase.json.

firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/bundled",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**/!{*.*}",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

polymer.json:

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/my-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/my-app.html",
    "src/my-view1.html",
    "src/my-view2.html",
    "src/my-view3.html"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "src/**/*",
    "images/**/*",
    "bower.json"
  ],
  "includeDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"
  ]
}
```

EDIT: Here is the routing section of the starter kit

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {
        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          observer: '_pageChanged'
        }
      },

      observers: [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)'
      ],

      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'view1';
      },

      _pageChanged: function(page) {
        // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
        var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
        this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
      },

      _showPage404: function() {
        this.page = 'view404';
      }
    });
  </script>
```

There is an importHref call in there, is there a better way to handle the routing here?

Any tips, tricks, or words of wisdom are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use `importHref`? Your `my-view1` has been registered multiple times. Check again to ensure that `my-view1` is not being registered more than once somewhere in your code.

Comment: I edited the question to show the routing portion with the importHref.

Comment: I suspect the value of `page` changes multiple times, causing `importHref` to import multiple `my-view1`.html. Maybe you can `console.log` the value of `page` to see how it changes during runtime.

Comment: I removed the importHref call in the main routing section and the problem cleared up. The error didn't appear when the project was run from an unbundled state. I'm guessing the polymer build process took care of importing all of those html files at once to cut down on resource requests.